# converting list comprehensions to nested loops causes an infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have a sample code that looks like this:

```
outputs = ['']
for ch in "abc":
    outputs = [i+j for i in outputs for j in [ch.upper(), ch.lower()]]
    print(outputs) # Debugging purposes
```

The ouput looks like this:

```
['A', 'a']
['AB', 'Ab', 'aB', 'ab']
['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
```

I thought the nested for loops version will simply looks like this:

```
outputs=['']
for ch in "abc":
    for i in outputs:
        for j in [ch.upper(),ch.lower()]:
            outputs.append(i+j)
            print(outputs) # Debugging purposes
```

However, the output is actually an infinite loop:

```
['', 'A']
['', 'A', 'a']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa', 'AaA']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa', 'AaA', 'Aaa']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa', 'AaA', 'Aaa', 'aAA']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa', 'AaA', 'Aaa', 'aAA', 'aAa']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa', 'AaA', 'Aaa', 'aAA', 'aAa', 'aaA']
['', 'A', 'a', 'AA', 'Aa', 'aA', 'aa', 'AAA', 'AAa', 'AaA', 'Aaa', 'aAA', 'aAa', 'aaA', 'aaa']
. . .
```

I believeit has something to do with the `for i in outputs` part (maybe need to add a condition that acts as a handler or something), but I couldn't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into your list comprehension code, you can see that `outputs` get overwritten for every iteration of the loop. But in case of nested loop code, `outputs` keep expanding. So, the second loop will have to loop more times than necessary.

Another problem is that in nested loop code you are printing once for every iteration of inner loop (in other words whenever `append()` is called) , while in list comp code you are doing it once for every iteration of the outermost loop.

The correct result can be achieve with help of another list like this -

```
outputs=['']
for ch in "abc":
    temp = [] # temporary list
    for i in outputs:
        for j in [ch.upper(),ch.lower()]:
            temp.append(i+j)
    outputs = temp # overwrite outputs
    print(outputs) # print only once per iteration of outer loop
```

Comment: You know what's funny, I did that too but it didn't work. Turns out the correct answer is the temp = [], not [''] Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good idea to modify a list while iterating over it - you have seen why this is the case. The object you are iterating over and the object you are appending to are the same, so as you append to the object that you iterate over you end up creating an infinite loop because you will never reach the end of the object.

As other answers point out, you can solve this by creating a temporary list and adding to that, then assigning that list to the list you are iterating over when the loop is finished.

Another method is to make a copy of the list when you start to iterate, like so:

```
outputs=['']
for ch in "abc":
    for i in outputs[:]:  # <== notice the [:]
        for j in [ch.upper(),ch.lower()]:
            outputs.append(i+j)
            print(outputs) # Debugging purposes
```

When you slice a list in python, it creates a copy of the list. So, in this solution you are iterating over a *copy* of the original list and not the actual original list. You basically are creating an implicit temporary array so you don't end up with the infinite loop.